# c++ functions while loop

Tags: c++, function, while-loop

When I type in a decimal for number of employees it outputs "Please enter a value of atleast 1" an infinite number of times. But shouldnt the decimal be truncated? How do i fix this so the decimal is erased. This happens for the input of daysMissed also.

```
#include <iomanip> 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int getNumEmployees();
int getDaysMissed(int);
double getAverageDays(int,int);

int main()
{
int numEmployees;
int daysMissed;
double average;

    //Get the number of employees
numEmployees = getNumEmployees();

//Get the number of days missed
daysMissed = getDaysMissed(numEmployees);

//Get the average days missed
average = getAverageDays(numEmployees, daysMissed);

cout << "The average number of days missed is: " << average << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}

int getNumEmployees()
{
    int employeeNum;

    cout << "Enter the number of company employees: ";
    cin >> employeeNum;

    while(employeeNum < 1)
        {
            cout << "Please enter a value of atleast 1 " << endl;
            cin >> employeeNum;
        }

    return employeeNum;
}


int getDaysMissed(int employeeNum)
{
int totalDays = 0;
int employee;

for(int count = 1; count <= employeeNum; count++)
{
    cout << "Enter the number of days employee " << count << " missed: ";
    cin >> employee;
    while(employee < 0)
        {
        cout << "Enter a positive number for days missed " <<     endl;
            cin >> employee;
        }

    totalDays += employee;
}
return totalDays;
 }

double getAverageDays(int employeeNum, int totalDays)
{
double averageDays;

averageDays = totalDays / employeeNum;

return averageDays;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

After each un successful `cin` operation you need to use:

```
cin.clear();
```

to reset the failure flag.
and then use:

```
cin.ignore();
```

to ignore the string that just caused the error so you don't attempt to parse it again.

You should be doing something like:

```
int employeeNum = 0;
cout << "Enter the number of company employees: ";

while (!(cin >> employeeNum) || employeeNum < 1)
{
    if(cin.fail()) 
    {
        cout << endl << "Please enter a valid value: ";
        cin.clear ();   // reset the "failure" flag
    } 
    else if(employeeNum < 1) 
    {
        cout << "Please enter a value of at least 1: ";
    }
    // ignore the bad charactors
    // needed here incase '0.XX was entered
    cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
}
```

If the value you enter is a decimal then the decimal will be truncated, not rounded.

The default for `ignore` is to only skip over 1 character, but if you expect to get a long invalid string (like a small decimal: 0.23), you should change the `ignore` to:

```
cin.ignore(10000, '\n')
```

Which will skip up to 10000 characters or until the next newline.

Comment: You might want to get rid of the offending character or line as well.

Comment: @chris quite true! forgot the ignore.

Comment: does it answer the question: "But shouldnt the decimal be truncated?"

Comment: @Serdalis cin is considered true when the stream is valid, even if user entered 0, so your code does not guarantee a value of at least 1. :)

Comment: @JiuDong True, the value is truncated, cin just puts 0 into employeenum on fail, sorry I consentrated on the wrong part of the problem, fixed now.

Comment: @user1807815 did you use this code? My tests were successful with inputs like: `a`, `0.23`, `1.23`, `1`, `0`, `2`, `2.23`.

Comment: @Serdalis i did the same code into the getNumEmployees function and it still does the same thing. What did you mean by the ignore at the end? If i put in cin.ignore it still does the same thing and if i put in just ignore it says ignore is undefined

Comment: @user1807815 sorry I missed the `cin` in that part of code. I was trying to say there that `cin.ignore()` will only skip 1 charactor, but `cin.ignore(10000, '\n')` will skip 10000 or to the first new line, since `cin` will only take in the int before the `.`, leaving the decimal as a seperate number.

Comment: @Serdalis It's still not working, its doing the same thing :/. I even tried copy and pasting it but no good. hmmmm

Comment: Your loop still spins spewing output on EOF.

Comment: @TonyD I tested EOF (CTRL + Z) on the console and it doesn't do anything except require you to enter the value 2x. No loop.

Comment: @Serdalis: that may be true for the very limited case of Windoze when input isn't from a pipe or redirection, but isn't good C++ general practice.

Answer (score 2):

```
int employeeNum;
cin >> employeeNum;
```

This code attempts to parse an `int` from `std::cin`.  Firstly, you're not actually checking the stream state afterwards - you assume that `employeeNum < 1` sufficiently communicates failure, but that's not normally the best approach: there could be an EOF or error condition on the input stream.  For the former your program might need to terminate, for the latter you probably want to ignore the rest of that input line and clear the error condition before retrying:

```
#include <limits>

if (std::cin >> employeeNum)
    break; // no need to retry input...
else if (std::cin.eof())
    throw std::runtime_error("EOF on input");
else
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n').clear();
```

> But shouldnt the decimal be truncated? How do i fix this so the decimal is erased.

If you want to input a real number then use its "truncated" value, you need to input to a `double` or `float` then convert it to an `int` in code.  Assuming you don't need range checking...

```
double x;
if (std::cin >> x)
{
    int x_int = x;
    ...use x_int...
}
```